# Как отфильтровать таблицу на основе данных из другой таблицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

есть три таблицы:

```
class Course(models.Model):

 name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 start_date = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 end_date = models.CharField(max_length=255)

 def get_count_student(self):

     count = CourseParticipant.objects.filter(course=self.id)
     return len(count)

 def __str__(self):
     return f'{self.name}'

class Student(models.Model):

 first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 email = models.CharField(max_length=255)

 def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.first_name}'

class CourseParticipant(models.Model):

 course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='course', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Хочу получить студентов которые не участвуют в конкретных курсах, выполняю следующий запрос

```
potential = Student.objects.exclude(courseparticipants__course=pk)
```

где в pk указываю id курса, в ответ получаю:

*django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'courseparticipants' into field. Choices are: email, first_name, id, last_name, student*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, у вас не правильные `related_name`

```
course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='course', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Что такое `related_name` ? Это название свойства у связанного объекта, которое используется для обращения к объекту, в котором указана эта связь.

Это значит, что для связи со студентами, `related_name` должен быть, например, `participantion`. Для курсов - `participants`.

Тогда получение доступа к этим данным из объекта `Student` будет выглядеть так

```
# student - объект Student
student.participantion.all() # queryset модели CourseParticipant
```

А теперь по вопросу. С учетом моих советов, надо написать так:

```
potential = Student.objects.exclude(participantion__course=pk)
```

Для вашего примера без моих правок

```
potential = Student.objects.exclude(student__course=pk)
```